# Car died at red light and now it won't turn over

Tags: starting, hyundai, stall, santa-fe

I have a 2004 Hyundai Santa few 2.7l v6. I've been having problems with this car for a while now. I've already put some money into it, I got the fuel pump, fuel pump relay, the alternator, ecm, and purge valve fixed. I just recently fixed the ecm it ran great right after we installed a used part we purchased. Today it started up great we drove maybe for 45 mins, stopped to get food (40 minutes at a restaurant) on our way out the car started and we drove out of the parking lot then we stopped at a red light right beside the restaurant and the car just died, we tried to crank it back up but once again it wouldn't turn over. I don't know what else I can do or fix. Please help!!!!!

Comment: Sounds like a dead battery, also check the charging system once it is running again.

Comment: If the battery was dead, wouldn't the lights in the car not come on? Well my lights still come on. It cranks but won't turn over

Comment: @Ingrid The battery power needed to run lights is much lower than what is needed to turn the engine over. Your battery may have dropped to a low charge either because the battery itself has gone bad, or your alternator has gone bad. Also, "cranking" and "turning over" are the same thing. What is your car doing exactly when you try to start? Do you hear a clicking sound, a soft whir or the regular sound of the engine trying to start?

Comment: I think she's saying the engine actually spins, but doesn't start ... we're mixing terms here. She's using "turn over" as "doesn't fire". @Ingrid ... you'd need to check fuses/relays to ensure the fuel pump is running (or can you hear the fuel pump kick in when you turn the vehicle to "on"?). Also check your fuses to your fuel injectors. I'd give you 10:1 this will turn out to have something happening with the fuel system, but it's really a swag.

Comment: I got the fuel pump fixed about 3 weeks ago and the ecu got fixed on Friday. I'll check my fuse again if I have to and the battery as while. And thank you @paulster2

Comment: I also got the alternator fixed about a month go

Comment: @Ingrid you mean engine turns over but won't start?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant